# Get a sibling web element using css selector

Tags: javascript, css, protractor

How can I get a reference to the `button`? which is always a sibling of the text I'm searching for.

In protractor test:

```
let spanText = 'My text';
let spanRef = element(by.css('span[name=' + spanText + ']'));
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <span name="My text">My text</span>
  <button type="button">
    Click me!
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
by.css('span[name=' + spanText + '] + button')
```

Note that you may want to add quotes to surround `spanText` since it contains a space. See [valid identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

With quotes and using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax:

```
by.css(`span[name="${spanText}"] + button`)
```

Comment: Good job using a CSS selector for that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe help you:

**Xpath**:

- //span[@name='My text']/following-sibling::button
- //span[contains(text(),'My text')]/following-sibling::button
- //div[span[@name='My text']]/button

**CSS**:

- span[name='My text'] + button